# Using SELECT Options outside of Fields in Angular-Formly

Tags: angular-formly

I have found Angular-formly and it looks awesome. However, I have found a problem. We load the array of options for our <SELECTS> using an Ajax call so the select options can come asynchronously.

Unless I am missing something (hopefully) it seems we need to have the array when we create the "fields" for the form.

I have set up an example here http://jsbin.com/tihofegifu/edit

Ideally I would like to load the Array for the SELECT OPTIONs via ajax and formly to use the options like standard Angular does.

Another issue is editing the array using angular as in the button will not work. 
What am I missing or doing Wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the example you're looking for is on [the website](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/other/async-select-options-with-controller). Basically, you create a `controller` for the field to do the loading for you. You could also define that controller as part of [a custom type](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/custom-types/custom-templates).

Alternatively, you could also use [`expressionProperties`](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/field-options/expression-properties) which can accept a promise and you could do:

```
expressionProperties: {
  'templateOptions.options': function() { /* return promise that resolves to the options you want*/ }
}
```

Good luck! Enjoy angular-formly :-)

Comment: Thanks @kentcdodds, but what if I want to "share" the list array, reuse the list?

Comment: There are many ways you could accomplish this. It really depends on your specific use case. I think the example you mentioned there is actually not a bad solution.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question - is there a way to use the controller's scope to get the options? I appreciate your time.

Comment: Yes. Isn't your example you provided doing that?